# How do I horizontally center a span element inside a div

Tags: css

I am trying to center the two links 'view website' and 'view project' inside the surrounding div. Can someone point out what I need to do to make this work?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F6R9C/

HTML

```
<div>
  <span>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">Visit website</a>
    <a href="#">View project</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div { background:red;overflow:hidden }

span a {
    background:#222;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:10px 10px 0 0;
    padding:5px 10px
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886460/center-align-span-text-inside-a-div

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center elements within a div, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 168, accepted):

One option is to give the `<a>` a display of `inline-block` and then apply `text-align: center;` on the containing block (remove the float as well):

```
div { 
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-align: center;
}

span a {
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    /* float:left;  remove */
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 5px 10px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Adrift/cePe3/

Comment: This did the trick for me in a moderately complex theme i needed to hack a bit. The link to JSFiddle further up was awesome to allow me to test. I edited this entry to include to change "overflow:hidden " to "overflow:hidden;"

Comment: Looks like a very clean solution.

Comment: See Ahmed Bahtity answer below, style="text-align:center", it's a lot more concise.

Answer (score 203):

Another option would be to give the span `display: table;` and center it via `margin: 0 auto;`

```
span {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Always interesting to see different solutuions to the same problem.

Comment: Only supported on browsers updated within the last couple years.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table

Comment: best solution IMO

Comment: Why do we need display: table;?

Comment: @kta otherwise margin auto wont work because span is normally like text, inline not block. Display table kind of combines the best of both worlds. If I remember...

Answer (score 19):

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <span>Short text</span><br />
    <span>This is long text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

Applying `inline-block` to the element that is to be centered and applying `text-align:center` to the parent block did the trick for me.

Works even on `<span>` tags.

Answer (score 3):

Spans can get a bit tricky to deal with. if you set the width of teach span you can use

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to center them, but they then end up on different lines. I would suggest trying a different approach to your structure.

Here is the jsfiddle I cam e up with off the top of my head: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T77x6/)

EDIT:

Adrift's answer is the easiest solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to center them on one line and not on two separate lines based on your fiddle.  If that is the case, try the following css:

```
 div { background:red;
      overflow:hidden;
}
span { display:block;
       margin:0 auto;
       width:200px;
}
span a { padding:5px 10px;
         color:#fff;
         background:#222;
}
```

I removed the float since you want to center it, and then made the span surrounding the links centered by adding margin:0 auto to them.  Finally, I added a static width to the span.  This centers the links on one line within the red div.

Answer (score 0):

only css div you can center content

```
div{
       display:table;
       margin:0 auto;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4q2r69te/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
span { width: 100%; text-align: center }
```

Worked for me. For me the parent element was a `<td>` though.