# Center align a span inside a div with an img element

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to center align a span inside a div, which also contains an img element.

```css
.element {
  display: inline-block;
}

.element img {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.element span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/35646/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  <span>hello</span>
</div>
```

or see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonaspraem/0ed2ruct/1/)

However the text wont vertical align. I have looked primary at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249359/is-it-possible-to-vertically-align-text-within-a-div). However `vertical-align: middle` does nothing here.

I also looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-in-a-div). However I will rather avoid anything `position: relative` & `position: absolute` workarounds for this. I also tried messing the `line-height` with no luck.

I even tried to set `height: 100%`on the span, as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886460/center-align-span-text-inside-a-div) suggests, but that does nothing either.

I basically looked at bunch of questions here on SO, it seems like css is so weird about this, that there basically is 12 approaches for a simple thing like this. Yet I can't seem to get 1 of them to work in my occasion.

What is up with this behavior?

EDIT:

Marked as duplicate to [How to Vertical align elements in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/how-to-vertical-align-elements-in-a-div) - I have explained that these solutions with line-height and vertical align doesn't work in my case as explained in the original question. The accepted solution did not work in this case. How is it a duplicate?

Comment: I reference 3 other questions and explain why this is different. "Marked as duplicate, no comments btw"

Comment: I have marked with 4 question as duplicate with more than 70 different answers

Comment: and you should not stick to the accepted answer, you should go throught ALL the answers

Comment: .. yeah, since I referenced 3 questions in the post, I have obviously looked at more than the accepted answer. The accepted answer and the question determines whether it is a duplicate or not. "Edit to explain why your question is different" - is just words to me. I get closed no matter the effort put into the prior research before the question.

Comment: proof of the duplicate : from the second question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image) the first answer : simply add `vertical-align:middle` to the image https://jsfiddle.net/jzp2s5gk/

Comment: @TemaniAfif I explained several times here, and in the question that `vertical-align: middle` doesn't work. You haven't even read the question

Comment: OMG you edited that in after I answered you. What sort of attitude is that.

Comment: The copy past simply did went so I edit .. but my first comment without the edit was clear : "add vertical-align to the image and it's from the duplicate" So before accusing me that I don't read your question (because I do) you should also take the time to read the duplicates and my comments. As a side note, closing a question as a duplicate is to help you not against you.

Comment: another proof of the duplicate: you accepted an answer that is provided in at least 3 of the questionz I added as duplicate if not all of them (you can go through all of them and you will see)

Comment: My point still stands. I can't use `vertical-align: middle` for this, because it pushes the root elements position. A part of the question is the prerequisite that no `vertical-align: middle` - The first question you marks as duplicate is exactly that. Your fiddle doesn't help me, since it ignores parameters from the question.

Comment: From the first question, 3rd answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31078418/8620333 .. compare with the answer you accepted

Comment: same question another answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51626821/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here is probably to use flexbox. If your flex-direction is `row` (which is default), you can use `align-items` to center the elements vertically and `justify-content` to justify the row to the left (the "start" of the flex container). Let me know if you have any questions!

```css
.element {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.element img {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.element span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/35646/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  <span>hello</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox for this. Sample:

```
.element {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Use `align-items: center` for vertical align and `justify-content: center;` if you need also horizontal align center.