# what is the method to have 2 columns in a single row?

Tags: ionic-framework, responsive-design, grid

i'm trying to develope an hybrid app with ionic 2, i don't have a lot of experience in this scope, but i have tried to develope small project.
I need to put two columns (50%) in a single row and I try this but it doesn't work for me:

```
    <div class = "row">
       <div class = "col col-50">col 1</div>
       <div class = "col col-50">col 2</div>
    </div>
```

Can someone help me?
Thank's

Comment: Im using ionic 2 too and i read the grid docs http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid and the examples are just like your code try without white spaces before and after `=`

Comment: ok, now i try to do it

Comment: it doesn't work also without white spaces

Answer (score 2):

This worked perfect for my:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row >
    <ion-col col-6>
      ...
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

If you use an *ngFor place it in your ion-col:

```
<ion-grid>
   <ion-row>
     <ion-col col-6 *ngFor = "let item of items">
       ...
     </ ion-col>
   </ ion-row>
</ ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using div, and you should be using span if you want them in same line

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="col-50"> </span>
    <span class="col-50"> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: i've tried it and now the columns are on the same line but they don't be the 50% of width

Comment: you gonna need a css for that

Comment: Well actually if you wanna make width on spans you gotta make em display:inline-block or a display:block and and that point you better of with just goin for div. See example http://jsfiddle.net/N9mzE/1/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085557/set-percentage-width-for-span-element

Comment: Just google span 50% width or something like that untill you get the css that works for you. I would've done it for you but no time at the momment

Comment: Let me know what worked for you when you get it so I can update the answer for future SOers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ionic 2 try this:

```
<ion-row>
      <ion-col width-50></ion-col>
      <ion-col width-50></ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

but it should be mentioned on their site:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#grid

Comment: i tried it, columns are on the same line but they don't be 50% of width

Answer (score 0):

Ionic automatically evenly distributes the columns width if none specified, at least for Ionic3 an onwards

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col>stuffhere</ion-col>
  <ion-col>stuffhere</ion-col>
<ion-row>
```

That's the tidy and effective way.