# Are <section>, <div>, and <span> all basically the same thing?

Tags: html

I hear they all are basically putting elements in groups, so could all these elements be used the same way?

Comment: On an HTML level, yes, they all do the exact same thing. But on a CSS or pragmatic level, they do separate things. It all depends on why you are grouping the specific elements together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<section>` *(also `<article>`, `<aside>`, and other HTML 5 additions)* and `<div>` *(been around forever)*, are very similar (except for SEO / semantic differences) -- but `<span>` is quite different.

All - even `<html>` and `<body>` - are just containers inside which you can put other containers/tags.

As an inline element, `<span>` has several limitations that the other two do not, a couple of which are:

- Cannot style/change height or width
- Cannot use margin to raise/lower it above baseline

**So what is span for?** It is usually used to enclose a string of text for any of the following purposes:

- Place some text into an invisible container in order to style it (assign an ID or class to the span to make that job easier)
- Place some text into an invisible container in order to target it for javascript manipulation
- javascript can inject or remove text from a container, like a span tag

**Making a span tag a bit more stylable:** If you add `display:inline-block` to the span, you can now give the container most of the above styles (margin, etc) that you could not do at its default setting of `display:inline`. *(Note that if you add `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` to a DIV, it will now behave like a span...*

References *(for further reading)* :

[What is the difference between <section> and <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939864/what-is-the-difference-between-section-and-div)

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/the-importance-of-sections/

[CSS width of a <span> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621401/css-width-of-a-span-tag)

[Does height and width not apply to span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491068/does-height-and-width-not-apply-to-span)

##### Note that:

`<p>` and `<h1>` etc are exactly the same - containers inside which you can put other containers/tags/text - but these are like `<span>` in that they ***come with*** some automatic formatting that you may (or may not) desire. The primary reason for the different tags (except for a little bit of auto-formatting/css) is for SEO (semantics).

IF, while reading this, you begin to suspect you can program an entire website using nothing but DIVs . . . you are right. CSS is hella powerful.